# Algorithm for counting number of paths in an X by Y grid

Tags: java

I'd like to create a program in Java that calculates the number of paths a robot can take from top left of a grid T(x, y)  to bottom left.. Using each square in the grid only once and using ALL the squares in the grid. The robot can move up down left and right, making it more complicated. I know it's a recursive program I just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: You can start using an IDE , write some code, come back with specific problem.

Comment: *"I just don't know where to start."*  Start at the top-left.

Comment: Describe in words how you would solve this problem recursively. Hint: if your robot is at (0,0), and he hasn't visited any cells, where can he go? If your robot has moved from (0,0) to (0,1), where can he go?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to implement this algorithm

Comment: If the robot is at (0,0) he can move North and East. And if it's at 1,1 it can move in all directions provided it hasn't visited any of those squares before

Comment: The grid has no obstacles so the algorithm is supposed to find all the possible ways to reach say (0,3) in a grid of (9,3)

Comment: Just implement [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) and count solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the number of free squares and when you reach the bottom left you check if you used up all squares.

```
static int countPaths(boolean[][] grid) {
    int freeSquares = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < grid[y].length; x++) {
            if(grid[y][x]) freeSquares++;
        }
    }
    return _countPaths(grid, 0, 0, freeSquares);
}

static int _countPaths(boolean[][] grid, int x, int y, int freeSquares) {
    if(!grid[y][x]) return 0;
    if(y == grid.length-1 && x == 0) { // bottom left
        if(freeSquares == 1) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    grid[y][x] = false;
    for(int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
        for(int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
            int newX = x+dx, newY = y+dy;
            if(newX < 0 || newY < 0 || newY >= grid.length || newX >= grid[y].length) continue;
            if((dx == 0 && dy == 0) || (dx != 0 && dy != 0)) continue;
            sum += _countPaths(grid, x+dx, y+dy, freeSquares-1);
        }
    }
    grid[y][x] = true;
    return sum;
}

public static void main (String args[]) {
    boolean[][] grid = {{true, true, true, false},
                        {true, true, true, false},
                        {true, true, true,  true},
                        {true, true, true,  true}};
    System.out.println(countPaths(grid));
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly.. Where can I modify the grid size? The current one is 4x4....for example if I need 6 by 8

Comment: Glad you like it. btw. you can use any arbitary grid size. Just create a boolean array of the right size and fill it with true.

Comment: Yeah I've been able to change the grid size very easily.. Thanks to you... You just wrote that off the top of your head? #just wondering

Answer (score 0):

So, what do you need to know? You need to know the current state of the board, and where the robot is. From that, you can explore each of the adjacent cells which haven't been visited yet. As you explore each cell, apply the algorithm *recursively* to explore their adjacent cells. Eventually, each exploration will either find the goal, or run out of opportunities.

The basic algorithm will look something like this:

```
explore(board, position) {
  if (position == goal) {
    count++
    return
  }
  board.mark(position)
  for cell in position.neighbors
     if not board.ismarked(cell)
       explore(board, cell)
  board.unmark(position)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do you make sure the robot visits every square in the grid?

Comment: Ah - I'd forgotten that requirement. It's very easy to modify the algorithm to do that. Implement and understand the algorithm, and you should be able to figure that out.

Comment: Alright lemmie try that.. Haha think I'll need help with some of it though. Voting up.